# Is there a word for the "ineffable" feeling when listening to a beautiful song?

Tags: word-request

When I listen to a beautiful piece of music, for instance [Quizas by Andrea Bocelli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MtfTU7TJZbY), I am feeling something is under my skin, moving. I don't know if there exists a word to express such an [ineffable](https://aeon.co/essays/what-if-anything-can-be-said-about-what-is-unsayable) feeling.

Comment: Is the feeling you are describing unique to only hearing music? Can the feeling you are looking to describe be felt with other things?

Comment: @EdmundReed Mostly music and MV. I may have experienced no such feelings for other things yet.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

My first thought was the word *goosebumps* (which often refers to literal goosebumps, but can be used figuratively as well, as in, "That music gives me [goosebumps](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2016/05/getting_chills_when_listening_to_music_might_mean_you_re_a_more_emotional.html)."). Then I saw an [article](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2016/05/getting_chills_when_listening_to_music_might_mean_you_re_a_more_emotional.html) that said:

> #### Why Does Great Music Give You the Chills?
>
> Have you ever been listening to a great piece of music and felt a chill run up your spine? Or goosebumps tickle your arms and shoulders?
>
> The experience is called **frisson** (pronounced *free-sawn*), a French term meaning “aesthetic chills,” and it feels like waves of pleasure running all over your skin.
>
> Listening to emotionally moving music is the most common trigger of frisson, but some feel it while looking at beautiful artwork, watching a particularly moving scene in a movie, or having physical contact with another person.

I don't think the word is all that well-known, but it might be exactly what you are experiencing. The word ***chills*** (used in the article's headline) might be a more well-recognized substitute.

Comment: More on the science of frisson and music can be found in [this Smithsonian article](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/researchers-look-what-happens-brain-when-music-causes-chills-180959481/).

Comment: +1 but that isn't the way I've heard the word pronounced in American English (or should I say American French?); the second syllable usually comes much closer to *sown/sewn* rather than *sawn* as in "sawn-off shotgun".

Comment: I sometimes describe it as "shivers down my spine."

Comment: Welp. I learned something new today.

Comment: When I've come across this word it's always been preceded by the indefinite article - ' a frisson of pleasure'; and the second syllable pronounced 'on' rather than 'awn'

Comment: But frisson sounds so tame, compared with the rapture experienced by the OP. I got a frisson of excitement listening Susan Boyle that first time, but Pink Floyd blows my mind.

Comment: @peterG - I think 'on' and 'awn' are pronounced the same, just like 'don' and 'dawn' are homophones (at least where I live). In any event, the pronunciation is in the original quoted article, not something I added in.

Comment: @J.R. Well I guess that's another one of the ubiquitous homophone-or-not comments we get on here!  'Don' and 'dawn' are not remotely homophones to my Br Eng (North West) ear.

Comment: @J.R. In most North American accents, "on" and "awn" are both pronounced /ɑːn/, where in British English, "on" is /ɒn/, and "awn" is /ɔːn/. The Cambridge Dictionary has "[frisson](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frisson)" as /ˈfriː.sɒ/ (UK), and /ˈfriːˈsoʊn/ (US). (Though the audio for the UK is actually /ˈfriː.sɒ̃/.)

Answer (score 7):

**euphoric** or **euphoria**

[dictionary.com:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphoric)

> But when I wrote the check, it was the most **euphoric** feeling.

[dictionary.com:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphoria)

> She was flooded with **euphoria** as she went to the podium to receive her Student Research Award.

Comment: "I wrote the check", "she went to the podium to receive" The question is about *listening to music*.

Comment: Please don't plagiarize. If you are "borrowing" example sentences from other dictionaries, [provide a link](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/euphoria).

Comment: Catharsis or cathartic may fit in certain situations as well, though I prefer Rudy's 'euphoria' here.

Comment: @J.R. - LMAO plagiarizing a dictionary :D

Comment: @Davor - It's not a laughing matter. We expect dictionary references to be cited on ELL.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard it referred to as an "Aesthetic Moment".

I am not a musician. I'd give a better reference if I could find one. The best I can do is say that I heard my daughter's high school chorus teacher use the phrase.

Another possible answer would be "bliss".

After reading JR's answer, it occured to me that a nice piece of music might give [The warm fuzzies](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/warm%20fuzzies)

In the time since I originally posted this, I've become aware of [ASMR](https://www.google.com/search?q=asmr%20meaning&oq=asmr&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4342j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which, as far as I can tell, is a more scientific explanation of "Warm Fuzzies"

Answer (score 3):

If the music so good it is sublime you might be experiencing "[numinous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/numinous)".

This word is for when something is so good that you can't help but detect a hint of divinity or spirituality in it. This is also good for when you have deep seated connection to your fellow humans, perhaps after some great work of good you all share in numinous solidarity.

Comment: [Nesciens Mater by Jean Mouton](https://youtu.be/_hZHKKD5ahk) is perhaps a good example of numinous music.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered [this article](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/music-give-chills-spine-brain-special-research-university-southern-california-a8043416.html) which explained that phenomenon, and find some good expressions from it:

1. music gives you **goosebumps**
2. have **intense reactions** to music
3. react to songs in this **heightened manner**
4. people experience **chills**
5. people get goosebumps upon listening to music
6. body completely **changes** when listening to the song
7. listening to supposedly "sad" songs could actually **boost** someone's mood